# laravel register user if the call to an api is returns a valid access token

Tags: php, laravel

I want to register a new user : the procedure is to call an api with a client id and a client secret and if everything is ok I save the user. If not I redirect with an error message.

But when I try to redirect to the register route inside my validator I got this error **Call to a member function validate() on string**.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $messages = [
        'client_secret.size' => 'Secret Id must be exactly 36 characters',
    ];

    $client_id = $data['client_id'];
    $client_secret = $data['client_secret'];

    $access = $this->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret);
    if($access == false){
        return route('register');
 }

 return Validator::make($data, [
      'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
      'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
      'role' => 'required|string',
      'country' => 'required|string',
      'client_id' => 'required|string',
      'client_secret' => 'required|string|size:36'
    ], $messages);
}
```

Comment: This is a wrong implementation. The validator function returns `route('register')` on failing to get access token this a string returned. But at the same time if the access token is fetched, you return a validator instance. The code that calls this will try to run the `validate` method which would fail in the first scenario. And the way this function is coded, you can't redirect from within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that before seeing your answer. I think it's similar.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $messages = [
        'client_secret.size' => 'Secret Id must be exactly 36 characters',
        'access_token.required' => 'We could not get an access token, make sure that the client id and the client secret are correct'
    ];

    $input = [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'role' => 'required|string',
        'country' => 'required|string',
        'client_id' => 'required|string',
        'client_secret' => 'required|string|size:36',
        'access_token' => 'required|string|min:10'
    ];
    $client_id = $data['client_id'];
    $client_secret = $data['client_secret'];


    $access = $this->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret);

    if($access == false){
        $data['access_token'] = 'false';
    }else{
        $data['access_token'] = $access ;
    }

    return Validator::make($data, $input, $messages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong implementation. The validator function returns route('register') on failing to get access token this a string returned. But at the same time if the access token is fetched, you return a validator instance. The code that calls this will try to run the validate method which would fail in the first scenario. And the way this function is coded, you can't redirect from within it. If you really need to then you could do something like this

Validator method

```
if($access == false) {
    throw new \Exception('Failed to get access token');
}
```

Calling logic

```
try {
    $validator = $this->validator($data);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect()->route('register');
}

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // handle
}
```

OR

Validator method

```
if($access == false) {
    return null;
}
```

Calling logic

```
$validator = $this->validator($data);

if ($validator === null) {
    return redirect()->route('register');
}

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // handle
}
```